# How to use Django models from one app for connection to db replica from second app?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-apps

My system consists of two applications which are separate Django **projects** (let's say **A** and **B**) with own default databases and own users. Application **B** also reads from the application **A** database **replica**.

To achieve such behaviour I included application **A** into **B**'s `INSTALLED_APPS` and can access db **replica** through its models. But everything that is related to users (permissions, groups) is messed.

Does using `django.contrib.auth` in both applications led to this behaviour, and is there a better solution to work with replica through Django ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed there is a better way. In django world it called DatabaseRouter.

You can read about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/

It is a very comprehensive guide how to achieve multi db env for your django app.

And you can always write custom DatabaseRouter class which allows you to define behavior like: read only, write only, full access per app label, or even your model name.

You can even do this manually (but I will not recommend this for you - as this probably require a lot of changes in the current codebase:

```
>>> # So will this.
>>> Author.objects.using('default').all()

>>> # This will run on the 'other' database.
>>> Author.objects.using('other').all()
```

Hope that help - if you have more questions - please ask.

Comment: I've already implemented custom db router and it works fine. The problem is that when Django resolves groups for user model of current application, it uses wrong relation in request: `relation "matrix_user_groups" does not exist
LINE 1: ... "auth_group"."name" FROM "auth_group" INNER JOIN "matrix_us...`, while it should be `omega_user_group`

Comment: Well you should use users related models from application A, or B - and do not mix them. Third option would be to extract users management to separate app - but this requires to change references in models. 

Is it a single django app? Or two separate 'big' django applications with multiple django apps inside? 

If you want to use single users management you probably need to rewrite app A or B a little (or a lot) depends on the size of the application.

Comment: Finally, we decided to set the exact class in project settings from which user model in application A should inherit so it is simple `django.db.models.Model` in application B. Thanks a lot!